# Can't Keep Pretty Url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I'd like to have url like

`mydomain/a/b` from `mydomain/page.php?a=$1&b=$2`

The htaccess file understand that I want to go to `mydomain/page.php?a=$1&b=$2` when i use `mydomain/a/b` but he change the urlname to `mydomain/page.php?a=$1&b=$2` and I don't want that, i want to keep `mydomain/a/b`.

Here is the htaccess file I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ page.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

Comment: `a/b` isn't a real directory

Comment: Here is what i got

`/test/1
Request URL: mydomain/test/1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Location:mydomain/page.php?a=test&b=1`

and   `mydomain/page.php?a=test&b=1
Request URL:mydomain/page.php?a=test&b=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK`

Comment: I don't want to redirect, i just want to rewrite my url, it doesn't work and i don't know why. It's like something rewrite the pretty url to make him like `mydomain/page.php?a=test&b=1 `

Comment: I find my solution. I was using http// on htaccess and it force redirecting the page. That's why the url change. But he doesn't find my page without it because i was using alias on my apache serv. So i needed to add Rewrite Base /v152/... to my htaccess and now it's work!